# Elasticsearch could not find keyword search

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch

I am going to a folder where there are PDF files. In the for loop I extract the text of each PDF file. The text (string) from my PDF file with the file names are stored in the JSON format named "e1". I then insert this e1 in the elastic search database.
The index number is increased in the for loop every time.

I want to be able to get a list of Json objects based on a keyword search.  So that I can see in which objects (the "e1" that I inserted in Elasticsearch) the keyword is present.
I now get the error DSL class `science` does not exist in query. While the word science appears many many times in the PDF!

```
import PyPDF2

def read_pdf(pdf_file):
    string_file=""
    read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
    number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
    for page_number in range(number_of_pages):
        page = read_pdf.getPage(page_number)
        page_content = page.extractText()
        string_file+=page_content
    return string_file

import glob
pdf_list=glob.glob('/home/Jen/Mongo/PDF/*.pdf')

from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es=Elasticsearch([{'host':'localhost','port':9200}])



count=0
for i in pdf_list:
    count +=1
    print(count)

    stringi = i.replace('/home/Jen/Mongo/PDF/','')
    text=(read_pdf(i))
    lowercase_name=stringi.lower()
    text=text.lower()
    e1={
    "filename":stringi,
    "text":text}
    res = es.index(index=count,doc_type='PDF',id=1,body=e1)

z=input("keyword")# I insert science here
z=z.lower()

from elasticsearch_dsl import Search

s = Search().using(es).query(z)
print(s)
```

**Update** This code does not print anything:

```
import PyPDF2

def read_pdf(pdf_file):
    string_file=""
    read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
    number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
    for page_number in range(number_of_pages):
        page = read_pdf.getPage(page_number)
        page_content = page.extractText()
        string_file+=page_content
    return string_file

import glob
pdf_list=glob.glob('/home/Jen/Mongo/PDF/*.pdf')

from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es=Elasticsearch([{'host':'localhost','port':9200}])



count=0
for i in pdf_list:
    count +=1
    print(count)

    stringi = i.replace('/home/Jen/Mongo/PDF/','')
    text=(read_pdf(i))
    lowercase_name=stringi.lower()
    text=text.lower()
    e1={
    "filename":stringi,
    "text":text}
    res = es.index(index="my_name",doc_type='PDF',id=count, body=e1)

print("Test")
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search    

s = Search(using=es, index="my_name").query("match", title="science")

response = s.execute()

for hit in response:
    print(response.hits)
```

Comment: how your mapping looks like?

Comment: What do you mean with mapping?

Comment: mapping of your index?!

Comment: @DejanMarić The index number is increased in the for loop every time. I updated the context of my question.

Comment: but you set id=1, so it's always _id=1 for every document. Maybe deleted docs are updated?

Comment: @DejanMarić No, As you see I have count=0 before the for loop. The print(count) also confirms that every time the count id increases with one! (I have tested this!)

Comment: please search on index (GET index/_search) and post your result, or GET /_cat/indices/ and post results. I think you are overriding still

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with this line of code:

```
res = es.index(index=count,doc_type='PDF',id=1,body=e1)
```

you are creating indices `0,1,2..N` (because count is from `0` to `N`), of type `PDF`, and every document in each index has `_id=1`

Check the [documentation](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/#example-usage)

It should be something like:

```
res = es.index(index="my_name",doc_type='PDF',id=count, body=e1)
```

and if you did correctly first part of data processing, you should have all documents in `my_name` index and each document would have his own `_id` (from 1 to N).

Just run in Kibana `GET _cat/indices?v` and check what you have with your slution and with these changes.

As a second part of question, you can search for "science" (for all documents) in `my_index` with:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "my_field": "science"
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATED**
or

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "my_field": "science"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE 2** (Python)

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search

client = Elasticsearch()

s = Search(using=client, index="my_index").query("match", title="science")

response = s.execute()

for hit in response:
    print(response.hits)
    # print(hit) / or print(hit.title, hit.id, ..)
```

Comment: I receive an invalid syntax Syntax Error when I try the second part of your code.(You are right about the first part of the error indeed)

Comment: which version of Elasticsearch do you use? See updated answer

Comment: I have version: 7.3.2.. I think the seconds part that you entered is not python code is that possible?

Comment: yes, it's query on Kibana. For query from python use docs: https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html

Comment: when i do "s = Search().using(es).query("match", title="science")" I get the with "print(s)" "<elasticsearch_dsl.search.Search object at 0x7f3e45e3c710>" but not the actual Json. How do I get the Json?

Comment: check updated answer again.. you get the result, but you are not printing them, need some "for" to do it

Comment: I updated my code: the for loop does not print anything.

Comment: try to search in Kibana, maybe you don't have correct data in Elasticsearch, I don't know how your pdf or data looks like. try GET my_index/_search in Kibana or curl -XGET localhost:9200/my_index/_search in shell and paste results

Comment: when I do "curl -XGET localhost:9200/my_name/_search" I don't get a Json object but I get: (very large string): "w\n2.1.2\n signi˚cant accounting considerations, policies˜and˜estimates\nthe group™s signi˜cant accounting considerations, policies \nand estimates are described in the notes to the consolidated " and it much larger than this

Comment: then you didn't parse your pdf context properly

Comment: I extract the text form the PDF as a string. Am I doing something wrong there or should approach it differently?

Comment: you need to put json, not string, elasticsearch store documents as json objects

Comment: I am inserting  an Json in elasticsearch like:  `e1={"filename":stringi, "text":text}` where stringi is a string of the filename and text is a string that has the complete content of the PDF file as a string.

Comment: then search for “science” in text field

Comment: should I change my query to: `s = Search(using=es, index="my_name").query("match", text="science")` instead of `s = Search(using=es, index="my_name").query("match", title="science")` ?

Comment: if all your json objects are in “text” field, then yes.